# Selecting an element based on a search of a subelement array returns the element once for each matching item in the array

Tags: jq

Given the json

```
{ "games": [
{
    "id":1,
    "files": [ "foo.mp4" ]
},
{
    "id":2,
    "files": [ "foo.ogv",  "bar.ogv" ]
},
{
    "id":3,
    "files": [ "bar.ogv" ]
}
]}
```

and the command
`jq -r '.games[] | select(.files[] | contains("ogv"))' foo.json`, `json` outputs an element once for every time it matches `ogv` in the subelement array. How do I get `jq` to output each matching element only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `any` would be more efficient than relying on `unique`. E.g.

```
jq -r '.games[] | select(any(.files[]; test("ogv")))'
```

Comment: This is correct except for a missing close parenthesis which I can't add because it is a less than six-character edit *groan*. The correct code is `jq -r '.games[] | select(any(.files[]; test("ogv")))'`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
jq -r '[.games[] | select(.files[] | contains("ogv"))] | unique | .[]' foo.json
```

or, since what I really want is just the `id`,

```
jq -r '[.games[] | select(.files[] | contains("ogv")) | .id] | unique | .[]' foo.json
```